# Can I extract skills from my weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have an Iron Maul of Flame.  It "Deals 40 Flame Damage".  I can destroy it for plain materials at the blacksmith.  Is there any way I can get something special out of an item like this?  For example, at the enchanting station?  (Although, I saw no option for this at the enchanting station.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. You can't get the weapon enchantment or other extras back from weapons and armors.**

You can get three types of items back by deconstructing one:

- **base material:** like wood, metal or cloth
- **the style material:** and only the one being used, limited to only those who can be crafted. Yokudan, for example, can't be extracted.
- **enhancement material:** only the ones fitting to your item enhancement level. So out of a fine (green) sword you are only able to draw out one [Honing Stone](http://elderscrollsonline.wiki.fextralife.com/Honing+Stone); a orange (legendary) one may give you one [Tempering Alloy](http://elderscrollsonline.wiki.fextralife.com/Tempering+Alloy).

Comment: More-or-less OT: Don't be sad, for leveling purposes you will always find enough enchantment runes for your armor/weapons and for late-game gear your guild mates will gladly help you creating them. :)

Comment: you can also research an item to get the *trait* from it, which is different than an enchantment (e.g. This item deconstructs for 280% inspiration / sells for 75% more, etc). this destroys the item in the process though, and takes a few hours IRL.

Comment: @Dpeif Bad examples imho, as neither of those traits (Intricate and Ornate) can be learnt by deconstruction.